# How to HandleValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a' without try except

Tags: python

When input is taken as an integer at the command line window and you give some string or character, the following error occurs:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

How to handle this without a `try-except` block?

Comment: This is what exception handling is *for*, why *not* use a `try:` statement here?

Comment: Probably you want to read the value as string using `raw_input` instead of `input`?

Comment: You need to tell us a little more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: my program is such that it should takes input as integer and whenever i input a character or string it should get handled without try except

Comment: fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1   --> this is how i take my command window input. Now whenever i enter some string/character it gives me error and i want to handle that

Comment: Then use `try:` for that. There is really *no* reason to not use an exception handler here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **have** to avoid using `try:`/`except:`, use:

```
def is_int_number(num):
    return num.strip().lstrip('-+').isdigit() and num.count('-') + num.count('+') <= 1
```

as a test; this matches *almost all* string values that `int()` will accept as a base-10 number:

```
>>> for v in [' +2 ', '-3', '     4', '5    ', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '...', '  +1458  ', 'Next']:
...     print '{!r} is {}'.format(v, int(v) if is_int_number(v) else 'not a number')
... 
' +2 ' is 2
'-3' is -3
'     4' is 4
'5    ' is 5
'6' is 6
'7' is 7
'8' is 8
'9' is 9
'10' is 10
'...' is not a number
'  +1458  ' is 1458
'Next' is not a number
```

In *normal* code, we use `try`/`except ValueError:`, however:

```
try:
    fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter a number')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: That is probably the best answer to your actual question, @Neeraj Lad, but you should **not** use it in your code anyway. Doing things like this, you are setting traps for yourself - edge cases that will blow up in your face in a worse possible moment.

Comment: Could your `is_int_number` also be implemented as `return re.search(r"^\s*[+-]?\d+\s*$", num)`?

Comment: @SethMMorton: It could; but that's an extra import and an OP that has an unexplained aversion to using exception handling may not be open to importing `re` either. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a try except, and catch the ValueError

Please review this python documentation:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid a try/except block, you could use the builtin [`isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method and do your check manually, but as other repliers, i'd recommend just using a try/except instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for-in block that verifies each character is a digit, or fails:

```
_zero = ord('0')
_nine = ord('9')

def is_num(value):
    for c in value:
        if not (_zero <= c <= _nine):
            return False

    return True

print(is_num(b'234'))
```

**It's important to mention that this strategy is not "Pythonic". It's preferred that you rely on exceptions whereever you can, and stay away from result checking as much as possible.**

Comment: fieldindex = int(sys.argv[1])-1 this is my command line input syntax and when i take string/character the above error is shown. Could you help me this with for -in block ?