# If error occurs, run new code

Tags: python, error-handling

This is my code:

```
for a in range (100):


        ser = serial.Serial(
            port = '/dev/ttyAMA0',
            baudrate = 38400,              #115200 is SMC-MRU, 9600
            parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
            timeout = 1
        )
        counter = 0

        while 1:
            x = ser.readline(18)
            x2 = x.split(',')
            Yaxis = float(x2[1])
            Xaxis = float(x2[0])
```

Occasionally i get an InvalidLiteral error.

To rectify this i have to run the code again changing:

```
x = ser.readline()
```

Cancel it, then put 18 back in the brackets and it works. I would like to incorporate that into the script, how to do this is what I'm asking.

Comment: Do you know about [try and except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) ?

Comment: What do you mean  by "cancel it"? is there a `.cancel()` method you're calling? Are you pressing ctrl-C? Is there a "reading line..." message box with a "cancel" button that you click?

Comment: Can you please print below ser.readline(18) when you get error. There should be problem with data contain here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IMCoins stated, [try / except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) is the solution you are looking for.

First, you can catch your *InvalidLiteral* exception (it should correspond to a *ValueError* type as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265128/how-to-handlevalueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-a-without-try)) and then deal accordingly. This works using the *except* instruction as a fallback:

```
while 1:
    try:
        x = ser.readline(18)
    except ValueError:
        x = ser.readline()
    x2 = x.split(',')
    Yaxis = float(x2[1])
    Xaxis = float(x2[0])
```

If your code inside the *try* fails with the specified *Exception* type, the corresponding *except* block will be executed. Note: it *won't* be executed if the code above succeeds.

At last, you also have the *finally* instruction, that is always executed afterwards, disregarding of the success/failure of the operations. As you stated you have to call it without parameter and then try again with it, you probably have to deal with the connection reset? My idea is:

```
while 1:
    try:
        x = ser.readline(18)
    except ValueError:
        x = ser.readline()
        # handle the serial connection reset here if needed before retrying
        x = ser.readline(18)
    x2 = x.split(',')
    Yaxis = float(x2[1])
    Xaxis = float(x2[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have tried this code and I will let you know if it fails; it is yet to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for a in range (100):


    ser = serial.Serial(
        port = '/dev/ttyAMA0',
        baudrate = 38400,              #115200 is SMC-MRU, 9600
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout = 1
    )
    counter = 0

    while 1:
        try:
            x = ser.readline(18)
        except ValueError:
            x = ser.readline()
        x2 = x.split(',')
        Yaxis = float(x2[1])
        Xaxis = float(x2[0])
```